# C best function to get split array on elements less, equals and greater than some value

Tags: c, algorithm, function

I am programming in C. What is the best method (I mean in linear time) to spit array on elements less, equals and greater than some value `x`.

For example if I have array

```
{1, 4, 6, 7, 13, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11}
```

and `x = 7` then it should be

```
{1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 13, 11 }
```

I don't want to sort elements because I need more efficient way. Of course in this example in could be any permutation of `{1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5}` and `{13, 11}`.

My thougt: less or grater than some element in array... In this example it is 7.

My function is:

```
int x = 7;
int u =0, z = 0;
for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)  // size - 1 because the last element will be choosen value
{
  if(A[i] == x)
    swap(A[i], A[u]);
  else if(A[i] == x)
  {
     swap(A[i], A[n-(++z)]);
     continue;
  }
  i++
 }

for(int i = 0; i<z; i++)
   swap(A[u+i],A[size-(++z)];
```

where u is number of current less elements, and z is the number of equals element

But if I  have every elements in array equals there it doesn't work (size-(++z)) is going under 0

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't notice. I corrected

Comment: "I don't want to sort elements" but you *are* sorting the elements.

Comment: No. I don't sort the elements. Less elements or greater than 7 are not sorted

Comment: Just my semantic quibble. If you rearrange some or all of the elements, you are sorting the array.

Answer (score 5):

This is the so-called [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem), named after the three-striped Dutch flag. (It was named that by E.W. Dijkstra, who was Dutch.) It's similar to the `partition` function needed to implement quicksort, but in most explanations of quicksort a two-way partitioning algorithm is presented whereas here we are looking for a three-way partition. The classic quicksort partitioning algorithms divide the vector into two parts, one consisting of elements no greater than the pivot and the other consisting of elements strictly greater. [See note 1]

The wikipedia article gives pseudocode for Dijkstra's solution, which (unlike the classic partition algorithm usually presented in discussions of quicksort) moves left to right through the vector:

```
void dutchflag(int* v, size_t n, int x) {
  for (size_t lo = 0, hi = n, j = 0; j < hi; ) {
    if (v[j] < x) {
      swap(v, lo, j); ++lo; ++j;
    } else if (v[j] > x) {
      --hi; swap(v, j, hi);
    } else {
      ++j;
    }
  }
```

There is another algorithm, discovered in 1993 by Bentley and McIlroy and published in their paper ["Engineering a Sort Function"](http://pauillac.inria.fr/%7Emaranget/X/421/09/bentley93engineering.pdf) which has some nice diagrams illustrating how various partitioning functions work, as well as some discussion about why partitioning algorithms matter. The Bentley & McIlroy algorithm is better in the case that the pivot element occurs infrequently in the list while Dijkstra's is better if it appears often, so you have to know something about your data in order to choose between them. I believe that most modern quicksort algorithms use Bentley & McIlroy, because the common case is that the array to be sorted has few duplicates.

#### Notes

1. The Hoare algorithm as presented in the [Wikipedia Quicksort article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), does not rearrange values equal to the pivot, so they can end up being present in both partitions. Consequently, it is not a true partitioning algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
1) Loop through the array, if element is less than x then put in new array1.
2)If element is greater than x then put in new array2.
This is linear time O(n)

Comment: and space O(n) as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this below which I think is O(n).  Took me a little bit to work the kinks out but I think it's pretty similar to the dutchflag answer above.

My ouptput

```
a.exe
1 4 6 5 3 1 7 7 11 13 
1 4 5 6 3 1 7 7 7 11 13
```

code:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
void order(int * list, int size, int orderVal)
{
  int firstIdx, lastIdx, currVal, tempVal;

  firstIdx = 0;
  lastIdx = size-1;

  for ( ;lastIdx>firstIdx;firstIdx++)
  {
      currVal = list[firstIdx];
      if (currVal >= orderVal)
      {
        tempVal = list[lastIdx];
        list[lastIdx] = currVal;
        lastIdx--;
        list[firstIdx] = tempVal;
        if (tempVal >= orderVal)
          firstIdx--;
      }  
  }
  lastIdx = size-1;

  for( ;lastIdx>firstIdx && middleNum>0;lastIdx--)
  {
      currVal = list[lastIdx];
      if (currVal == orderVal)
      {
        tempVal = list[firstIdx];
        list[firstIdx] = currVal;
        firstIdx++;
        list[lastIdx] = tempVal;
        if (tempVal == orderVal)
          lastIdx++;
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int i;
  int list[] = {1, 4, 6, 7, 13, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11};
  int list2[] = {1, 4, 7, 6, 7, 13, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11};

  order(list, ARRAY_SIZE(list), 7);

  for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE(list); i++)
    printf("%d ", list[i]);
  printf("\n");

  order(list2, ARRAY_SIZE(list2), 7);

  for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE(list2); i++)
    printf("%d ", list2[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried that with the vector `{1,4, 7, 6, 7, 13, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11}` and it output `1 4 5 6 13 7 1 3 7 11 7`. But even with your input, the result is `1 4 6 5 3 1 7 13 11 7`  which does not have the two sevens adjacent.

Comment: @rici thanks for pointing that out.  There was an error in the logic.  I'm not sure the sevens need to be adjacent.  He did say he didn't want the output sorted.  Here's the output I get now...
`1 4 6 5 3 1 7 13 11 7 `
`1 4 5 6 3 1 7 13 7 11 7`

Comment: I think the OP unambiguously requests a three-way partition ("less, equals and greater"), and the example certainly shows that. Your program seems to implement the [Lomuto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)

Comment: I totally missed that point.  I've added another loop to process the middle list.  I've been counting loop iterations and it still seems more or less O(n).  Maybe not so optimal anymore though...

Comment: You might want to explore the links in my answer. A lot of people have analyzed different algos for two- and three-way partitioning, and if you're interested in that sort of thing, there is a lot to be learned about analysis of algorithms (and also verification).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using a bubble sort. Which type of sort algorithm is best, is up to you, this is just to demonstrate. Here, I treat values < x as `-1`, values == x as `0`, values > x as `1`.

Note that the elements < x and those > x are still in the same sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    int array[] = { 1, 4, 6, 7, 13, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11 };
    int x = 7;
    int len = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
    int i, j, m, n, tmp;

    for (i=0; i<len-1; i++) {
        m = array[i] < x ? -1 : array[i] == x ? 0 : 1;
        for (j=i+1; j<len; j++) {
            n = array[j] < x ? -1 : array[j] == x ? 0 : 1;
            if (m > n) {
                tmp = array[i];         // swap the array element
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = tmp;
                m = n;                  // and replace alias
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1 4 6 1 3 5 7 7 13 11
```

Comment: Maybe because the OP asked for an efficient solution and your suggested one is O(n^2)

Comment: @user2697817 thank you, the aim was to show that a sort **is** required, which in top comments OP denied. I did imply it's not the most efficient (the Dutch flag answer was posted while I prepared this) but it's not actually wrong.